# Generate String Value Table Automatically in EF Core

Tags: database, postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I have a table called `Customer` that has several columns called `National Code` and `Name`. It also has a number of other features called `Contact Numbers` and `Recommenders`, since the number of `Contact Numbers` and `Recommenders` is more than one, so you need some other table to store them.
Also suppose I have other tables like the `Customer`, each of which has a number of attributes greater than one.

1. What is your suggestion for storing these values?
2. In one source, it was suggested that for each table, a table called `StringValue` be used for storage. Does `EF core` have a way to implement `StringValue` without writing additional code?

**Example:**

```
   Customer Table:

   CustomerId         Name         NationalCode
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1                 David         xxxx
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  
   

   StringValue Table:

   StringId         CustomerId         StringName         Value
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   10                 1                PhoneNumber        915245
   11                 1                PhoneNumber        985452
   12                 1                PhoneNumber        935446
   13                 1                Recommenders       Mr Jhon
   14                 1                Recommenders       Mr bb
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Before you choose the path of EAV (Entity Attribute Value), do your research to understand the implications. It is very flexible - at the potential cost of considerable complexity and inefficiency.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. what do you suggest that is flexible and efficient?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is more intutive create a new table for the field which has more than one records, then configure a one-to-many relationship between the two tables. Take your case as an example, you can divide the customer table into three tables, they can be linked by foreignkey:

**1.Customer Table:**

```
CustomerId        Name         NationalCode
---------------------------------------------
1                 David        xxxx
```

**2.Contact Table:**

```
Id        CustomerId         PhoneNumber
---------------------------------------------
1         1                  915245
2         1                  985452
3         1                  935446
```

**3.Recommender Table:**

```
Id        CustomerId         RecommenderName
---------------------------------------------
1         1                  Mr Jhon
2         1                  Mr bb
```

Comment: Thanks for Answer. But I need some better solution.